# Angular keypress event's first value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I'm using Angular 11 for my project. In this project trying to send value from child component to parent component by changing value in child component's input field.

here is child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @Output() onChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() onChangedName = new EventEmitter<string>();

  change(increased: any) {
    this.onChanged.emit(increased);
  }

  changeName(name: string) {
    this.onChangedName.emit(name);
    console.log(this.name);
  }


}
```

child.component.html

```
<input type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="name"
       (keypress)="changeName(name)">
```

and parent component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  clicks: number = 0;
  name: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChanged(increased: any) {
    console.log(increased);
    increased === true ? this.clicks++ : this.clicks--;
  }

  onChangedName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<h3>{{name}}: name</h3>
<app-child
  (onChangedName)="onChangedName($event)"
  (onChanged)="onChanged($event)"></app-child>
```

I need to emit value from child and show it in parent component, but it seems work wrong, because the first value is 'undefined' and after rest inputs of name is less by one letter.
how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for model change instead:

```
<input type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="name"
   (ngModelChange)="changeName(name)">
```